# Regex/Javascript function to store prices as cent-based numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex is one of those areas where you think you have a decent solution until something breaks that you didn't consider in the first place.

I am trying to get prices from a string, like this:

```
US$1234.56
$12
$12.34usd
$0.56
.56 dollars
```

and convert them to:

```
123456
1200
1234
56
56
```

respectively. This is so that they can be stored as `Numbers` in my database for indexing purposes, so I'm storing the value as cents.

Presently I'm doing this with regex:

```
var justPrice = fullPrice.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

this works but doesn't account for a leading `0`, nor does it work to make `$12` === `1200` (rather than just `12`, which would be 12 cents).

I'm assuming there's no way to do this logic in vanilla regex, so using some javascript is fine here. what's the best way to achieve the results above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to grab the value from the string with any decimal place, then covert the string to a number and multiply by 100.

```
var stringPrice = fullPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
var justPrice = Number(stringPrice) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I think this is a case in which using a RegEx might not be the best idea. You could try something like this instead:

```
var priceParts = fullPrice.split('.'), justPrice = 0;
if (priceParts.length > 1) {
    if (priceParts[0] !== '' && priceParts[1] !== '') {
        justPrice = priceParts[0].replace(/\D/, '') * 100
                    + priceParts[1].replace(/\D/, '');
    } else if (priceParts[0] !== '') {
        justPrice = priceParts[0].replace(/\D/, '') * 100;
    } else if (priceParts[1] !== '') {
        justPrice = priceParts[1].replace(/\D/, '');
    }
} else {
    justPrice = priceParts[0].replace(/\D/, '') * 100;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't RegEx a good idea here? Seems to work fine / with significantly less code for the mostpart.

Comment: @Jascination This is my opinion, but I think that in this case it's easier to divide in cases (there is decimal part, there isn't, etc.) and manually act according to it. It's longer but safer in my eyes.